# How to remember the template type of a shared_ptr after assigning nullptr

Tags: c++, c++11, polymorphism, smart-pointers

How to remember the template type of a shared_ptr after assigning nullptr?

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class Base
{
public:
    virtual std::string toString() { return "base"; }
};
class Derived1 : public Base
{
public:
    virtual std::string toString() override { return "derived1"; }    
};
class Container
{
public:
    std::shared_ptr<Base> mMember;

    template<class actualType>
    void InitializeMember()
    {
        mMember = std::make_shared<actualType>();
    }

    void PrintMember()
    {
        if (mMember)
            std::cout << mMember->toString();
    }

    void RemoveFromMemory()
    {
        mMember = nullptr;
    }
    void ReCreateInMemory()
    {
        // mMember needs to be a shared pointer to a new Derived1 object
    }
};

int main()
{
    Container container;

    // one time initialization
    container.InitializeMember<Derived1>();
    container.PrintMember();
    // ...
    container.RemoveFromMemory();

    // I need container to allocate a new derived class in mMember
    container.ReCreateInMemory();
    container.PrintMember();
}
```

How can I implement ReCreateInMemory(), so that main() prints "derived1" for a second time?
The only time I want to pass the actual type is ONCE in the InitializeMember function.
Thanks.

Comment: The template type doesn't change when you assign a nullpointer.

Comment: Do you really need to have `void ReCreateInMemory()`?  Can't you just use `container.InitializeMember<Derived1>();` if you want to recreate the objecy?

Comment: `shared_ptr` can't help you here. You must store the type in some other way.

Comment: @NathanOliver Good idea, but only clients know which derived type they are using. The framework code shouldn't. And I don't want to rewrite all the clientcode.

Comment: make a `virtual void recreate() = 0;` method in Base, implement it in each Derived class and just call `mMember->recreate();` in `Container::ReCreateInMemory()`

Comment: @m88 won't work very well if `mMember` is null

Comment: @AlanBirtles `if (!mMember) return;` at the beginning of `ReCreateInMemory()` then

Comment: @m88 I think the point of `ReCreateInMemory` is to create a new object after `RemoveFromMemory` is called though

Comment: Alan is right. At that point the mMember is nullptr already. (eg. it got destructed)

Answer (score 4):

It will cost you another class member but you can leverage a `std::function` and a lambda to create a factory function to make objects of the specified type. You can turn your class into

```
class Container
{
public:
    std::shared_ptr<Base> mMember;

    template<class actualType>
    void InitializeMember()
    {
        factory = [](){ return std::make_shared<actualType>(); };
        mMember = factory();
    }

    void PrintMember()
    {
        if (mMember)
            std::cout << mMember->toString();
    }

    void RemoveFromMemory()
    {
        mMember = nullptr;
    }
    void ReCreateInMemory()
    {
        mMember = factory();
    }
private:
    std::function<std::shared_ptr<Base>()> factory;
};
```

and now you've stored a way to create the object you create in `InitializeMember()`

Comment: Works nicely. Thank you!

Comment: @carloselfietro You're welcome.  Glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility would be to create a factory function pointer in `InitializeMember` which you can then call again later to create another object.

```
class Container
{
public:
    std::shared_ptr<Base> mMember;

    template<class actualType>
    void InitializeMember()
    {
        mMemberFactory = [](){ return std::make_shared<actualType>(); };
        ReCreateInMemory();
    }

    void PrintMember()
    {
        if (mMember)
            std::cout << mMember->toString();
    }

    void RemoveFromMemory()
    {
        mMember = nullptr;
    }
    void ReCreateInMemory()
    {
        mMember = mMemberFactory();
    }
private:
    std::function<std::shared_ptr<Base>()> mMemberFactory;
};
```

You could also allow passing arguments to the constructor:

```
    template<class actualType, typename ... Args>
    void InitializeMember(Args&& ... args)
    {
        mMemberFactory = [args...](){ return std::make_shared<actualType>(args...); };
        ReCreateInMemory();
    }
```